# Which advantage does the WebAPI controller give over the MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an MVC5 site that uses the WebAPI. I have defined a helper class that handles some logging for the incoming request, which can be called for any action that needs to log data about the request made. (Mostly IP address, referrer, url and user agent, plus some header values.) And I've hit a snag...
The Controller class has a property Request that I use which is of type 'HttpRequestBase'. I had assumed the Request property in ApiController would be the same type but no, it's of 'HttpRequestMessage'.
This is annoying so it got me wondering if I really need the WebAPI inside my project. I wanted to use the WebAPI to return various data to be used by the site itself. Why not use a regular controller instead of the ApiController? What's the gain from using the ApiController and the Controller in a single project?

---

Please don't give opinions about why the WebAPI is better (or not) than using a regular controller. I need to know which technological advantage the use of WebAPI has next to a controller instead of just using a controller!

Comment: If you have MVC, there's basically no need for using Web API. Web API is more geared towards services that do not have the entire MVC libraries as dependencies.

Comment: Am i right to guess the Logger helper class is a static class, which have some kind of Log(HttpRequestBase) method ? And how exactly you call the Logger method ? Please provide us with code samples.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. There're technical differences between an `ApiController` and a `Controller`.

Comment: As Camilo says, there is a clear technical difference between both so it has nothing to do with opinions. It has to do with the very different implementations behind both techniques while they seem so similar. What is to gain from using the ApiController over the regular one? Technically speaking...

Comment: Almost, @orel Eraki. It's not static, though. A static class would cause problems if two or more requests are made at the same time. An ActionResult methods gets called, creates a helper object with the request it got and validates the result to see if the action will be valid. I'm keeping track of changes in the database so the helper class will link any change in the database to the request that caused the change. (For historic purposes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAPI controllers are specifically for API's whereas MVC controllers are more geared towards returning views.

Although both can handle both cases, WebAPI controllers have a few features that make it easier for API's:

- More explicit response code
- Content negotation
- Naming convention for get, post, put, delete, ... verbs
- ...

The distinction between the two types of controllers is a bit unfortunate. In the end, they do the same thing.

This is also the reason why in ASP.NET core, WebAPI and MVC have been merged. You won't find the discrepancies in ASP.NET core that you describe. If this is an option for you, you could go that way.

Comment: "Although both can handle both cases", are you sure? I don't think an `ApiController` has `View`/`PartialView` return helpers.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but there's no reason a WebAPI controller couldn't return an HTML string and set the content-type to text/html. It would be a completely backwards way of doing things, but still possible.

Comment: It could, but it wouldn't have a `ViewBag` or `ViewData` and it couldn't process actual views. Not without some modifications, at least.

Comment: True, what I mean is that they both handle an incoming HttpRequest and return an HttpResponse. They differ in how they do it, but what they do is the same.